# Magento store back URL

Tags: php, magento

Hi Here's a question for the Magneto folk here.
I'm trying to get the previous pages URL for a back button purpose (JavaScript's history wont work for my usage).
Here's what i got:

```
<li><a class="btn-go-back" href="<?php
                            $currentUrl = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
                             echo  Mage::registry('backUrl');
                            ?>" >Go Back</a></li>
                    <?php if(Mage::registry('backUrl')!= $currentUrl)
                        Mage::unregister ('backUrl');
                        Mage::register('backUrl' , $currentUrl, true ); ?>
```

The code is not clean, but it dosn't even work.

For some reason i get the current URL's link.

This is places in a views phtml.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information isn't sent normally by Magento, so you may want to add an observer or add the functionality in index.php file to saves the last access url in the session. This trick will save the last page from /any/ tab, not necessarily for the referring page.

Comment: Thanks.
But that is what im doing here.
Mage::register('backUrl' , $currentUrl, true ); ?>
Why would that show the current pages url?

Answer (score 4):

Magento does store a `last_url` property in session:

```
$_SESSION['core']['last_url']
```

Only issue with it is you can't tell what that page was (without inspecting the URL), but if you're using `Go back` as the anchor text it shouldn't matter.

Comment: The issue seems like the cache is storing the footer and therefore the footer block/controller never gets called...